# CSS Help Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using a WordPress theme and I'm having trouble removing the hover effect. As you can see when hover over a navigation item 2 box's show up  The effect creates two a white box's over the link, it looks unusual and I wish to remove it. I've tried a lot of ways to remove it but it still remains.

The effect I mention is on the NavBar.[image: This is what I am talking about]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find this line in your `CSS`:

`.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus`

and remove any mention of `box-shadow`

Another option is to do this, but it's not the cleanest as it uses `!important`:

```
#menu-item-50 a {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much the !important is what i needed

Comment: @NubmcNub my answer as the correct one, the tick that's greyed out, please click it

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution , if you remove the box shadow then you are good to go.

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus{

/* no need for box shadow */

}
```